# Derby GRANT statement using for give privileges to a specific user

Tags: java, database, derby, privileges

I have created Database with `sqlAuthorization` and some Tables in `Derby`. When i add some `fullAccessUsers` to system, users can't reach to tables because privileges. I use `GRANT` statement for users but don't help. I share my code below;

**Creating DB;**

```
String owner = "admin";
String ownerp = "admin";
String user1= "testuser";
String user1p = "testuser";
String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby://10.90.232.2:1527/myDB"+";user="+"\""+owner+"\""+";create=true";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
```

**Setting DB Properties;**

```
Class.forName(driver);
connectionURL = "jdbc:derby://10.90.232.2:1527/myDB"+";create=false;user="+"\""+owner+"\""+";password="+"\""+ownerp+"\""+";";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
Statement s = conn.createStatement();

//Setting DB to Require Authentication
s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
                "'derby.connection.requireAuthentication', 'true')");

//Setting DB to SQL Authorization                           
s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
                "'derby.database.sqlAuthorization', 'true')");

//Setting DB to SQL Authorization                         
s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
                "'derby.authentication.provider', 'BUILTIN')");

//Creating owner username and password
s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
                "'derby.user."+"\""+owner+"\""+"', '"+"\""+ownerp+"\""+"')");

//Creating testuser username and password
s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
                "'derby.user."+"\""+user1+"\""+"', '"+"\""+user1p+"\""+"')");

//Set both owner and user as a fullAccessUsers (read/write)
s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
                "'derby.database.fullAccessUsers', '"+"\""+owner+"\""+","+"\""+user1+"\""+"')");

//Setting DB to No Access for restrict unauthorized users
s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
                "'derby.database.defaultConnectionMode', 'noAccess')");

s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
                "'derby.database.propertiesOnly', 'false')");
s.close();

//This method shutdown the derby for take parameters.
shutDownDerby();
```

**Creating Table;**

```
//This method start the Derby Network Server
startDerby();

String connectionUrl2 = "jdbc:derby://10.90.232.2:1527/myDB"+";user="+"\""+owner+"\""+";password="+"\""+ownerp+"\""+";"; 
Connection con2 = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl2);
java.sql.Statement stmt2;
stmt2 = con2.createStatement();

//Creating Schema
stmt2.execute("CREATE SCHEMA TEST");

//Creating Table in TEST Schema
String query1 = "CREATE TABLE TEST.USER_INFO\n" +
                "(\n" +
                "USERNAME VARCHAR(80),\n" +
                "INFO VARCHAR(160)\n" +
                ")";

stmt2.execute(query1);

//This one should GRANT permission for reach TEST.USER_INFO to testuser but NOT!
stmt2.execute("GRANT SELECT ON TABLE TEST.USER_INFO TO testuser");
```

I succesfully connect to DB with `testuser`. But when i try Select from `TEST.USER_INFO` with `testuser` i receive below `SQLException`;

**Select Query;**

```
String query = "SELECT USERNAME, INFO FROM TEST.USER_INFO";
```

**SQLException;**

```
ERROR 42502: User 'testuser' does not have SELECT permission on column 'USERNAME' of table 'TEST'.'USER_INFO'.
```

If i connect to DB with DB Owner, Select statement return `resultset` succesfully. What am i missing in `GRANT` Statement i don't understand.

Comment: Is it a case-sensitivity thing? Did you actually grant select to TESTUSER, but you are connecting to the database as testuser? Try doing another grant statement, making sure to specify testuser in quotes so that you will grant to the all-lower-case testuser: 'grant select on test.user_info to "testuser" '

Comment: Bryan save me again thank you :) Really i am not get used to this `case-sensitivity` in Derby. If you remember i ask similar thing for user name in `connectionURL`. Anyway `stmt2.execute("GRANT SELECT ON TABLE TEST.USER_INFO TO "+"\""+user1+"\"");` working fine. You can write as answer.

Answer (score 0):

As a brief note this is a problem with the fact that per the specification, SQL identifiers are supposed to be folded to upper case.   So without double quotes, `testuser` becomes `TESTUSER` and this is not limited to Derby.  Oracle, FirebirdDB and others follow this same behavior (btw PostgreSQL folds to lower case, and MySQL preserves case so this may be part of the reason for the confusion).

Case folding is a particularly troublesome area in SQL-supporting databases because very few people actually like the standard-mandated behavior (as the PostgreSQL team says, it is irredeemably broken) and so projects get to choose between behavior almost nobody likes and behavior that is non-standard.